# extjs tagfield handle new

Tags: extjs, tags, extjs5

I have a tag field with the following configuration

```
{
        forceSelection: false,
        createNewOnBlur: true,
        createNewOnEnter: true,

        pageSize: true,
        minWidth: 340,
        // Note that everything is remote
        queryMode: 'remote',
        remoteFilter: true,
        remoteSort: true
}
```

What I want to achieve is:

- to add the ability to create new model but not just like this, with a form : for example when the user type "ENTER", i catch the event, display a form, do stuff and after validation, add the record to value
- to show something like "blabla *(new)*" when the record has not been found

Any idea how to perform this?
Thanks in advance,
PsychoKrameur

EDIT: Even if it's for for perfect I found a way to achieve the first part.
I override the following methods:

- setValue
- doSetValue

And I had a event *beforecreatedrecord* which can stop the execution.
On my controller, I check if the record is *phantom* or not, if yes I stop the execution till the creation of the record and then request a setValue again.

See part of method that I override :

```
setValue: function(value, /* private */add, skipLoad) {
    // ...
                if (!valueRecord) {
                    if (me.forceSelection) {
                        unknownValues.push(record);
                    }
                    else {
                        valueRecord = {};

                        // OVERRIDE
                        // remove the set of the id to have the model phantom (in my case valueField was the id)
                        //valueRecord[me.valueField] = record; 
                        valueRecord[me.displayField] = record;

                        cls = me.valueStore.getModel();
                        valueRecord = new cls(valueRecord);

                        //  Send a event that can stop execution
                        if (me.fireEvent('beforecreaterecord', me, valueRecord, record) === false) {
                            // if false stop here
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
     //..
},


doSetValue: function(value /* private for use by addValue */, add) {
    //...
                // We are allowing added values to create their own records.
                // Only if the value is not empty.
                if (!record && value[i]) {
                    dataObj = {};
                    dataObj[me.displayField] = value[i];

                    // OVERRIDE
                    // APPLY THE SAME PRINCIPLE AS ABOVE

                    //                                if (me.valueField && me.displayField !== me.valueField) {
                    //                                    dataObj[me.valueField] = value[i];
                    //                                }
                    record = new Model(dataObj);

                    if (me.fireEvent('beforecreaterecord', me, record, dataObj) === false) {
                        // if false stop here
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes and no. For now I have only a workaround for the first part. See my edit.